# JavaCC left recursion parsing question about legality of breaking down a grammar

Tags: compiler-construction, javacc, left-recursion

I'm attemping to do compilers on javacc but I'm not sure if the following is  legal when removing left recursion:

```
A = B AP APP
      | C AP APP

AP = A AP | {}

APP = (D AP) APP | {}
```

Comment: There's not enough information in the question to answer it. Which are the terminals and which are the non-terminals?  Which nonterminal is the start non-terminal?  Once those questions are answered, you can tell whether the grammar is LL(1). If it is, then it should work with JavaCC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that B, C, and D are terminals.  And I'm going to add one more nonterminal

```
START --> A <EOF>

A --> <B> AP APP
     | <C> AP APP

AP --> A AP | {}

APP --> <D> AP APP | {}
```

The first choice is clearly resolvable on one token of look ahead.  For the second choice we need that the first set of `A AP` be disjoint from the follow set of `AP`; the former is `{<B>, <C>}` and the latter is `{<EOF>,<D>}`.  For the third choice, we need that `<D>` is not in the follow set of `APP`, which is `{<EOF>}`.

We now know the grammar is LL(1), so it should work with JavaCC.

Note: Determining whether a grammar will work with JavaCC is a bit more complicated, because JavaCC doesn't calculate follow sets exactly like the theory says and because JavaCC has lots of mechanisms that allow it to work with non-LL(1) grammars. But generally if your grammar is LL(1), JavaCC will handle it fine. Also if JavaCC isn't going to work, it gives a warning message.